# How to delete component stuck in workflow

Tags: 2011, workflow

I m using tridion 2011 sp1 due to some script error my component is stuck in workflow in automatic decision activity now either i m not able to delete it or i m not able to update the process definition i m getting error

**it is not possible to update the process definition because it has active instance.**

what to do in this situation??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Workflow Administrator should force the activity finishing in the Workflow Administration section available in CME.

Comment: If you want to proceed with workflow - finish activity, if you want to get rid of component - Force finish process

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you need to finish the process. Here's a pointer to [a blog I wrote ages ago showing how you can automate this](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/using-powershell-to-do-useful-things-with-xml-lists-from-tridion). It's a bit out-of-date now, but you could easily update it to use the core service. Of course, it's not really useful to automate this if you're only doing it once (my use-case was for during development). Still - it might be useful to some of the people who come here to read this question.